# Suspend closes all application

Tags: suspend

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on Asus Vivobook F571. I have 12GB of RAM and 12GB of swap-area. When I suspend my laptop and resume back, all the applications are closed and the laptop takes similar time to resume as it takes to turn on after switch off. How to put it in normal sleep mode.

Comment: That's not usual behavior. Check /var/log/syslog for sleep- or resume-related errors

Comment: @user535733 I am new to ubuntu. I don't understand much.

Answer (score 1):

Suspend is behaving normal after disabling **secure boot** from BIOS.